# How to create a button with a clear background

Tags: ios, uibutton

How can I create a UIButton that is transparent other than its image?

I have PNG with a transparent background. I create a button with it, and I get the image in blue tint.

If I set tintColor to clearColor, the tint goes away but so does the black image.

I've been using UIButtonTypeSystem as the button type.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem] ;
button.frame = rect ;
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] ; // Does nothing
button.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor] ;  // Makes the button go away.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a transparent button, you should make it of type custom. So your code would become:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = rect ;
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] ; // This is not necessary, unless you want to specify a color - say [UIColor redColor] - for the button
```

Since UIButtonTypeCustom does not behave the same way as UIButtonTypeSystem, you should look at the various boolean flags to set specific traits. They would have to be set manually or through Interface Builder. Here are the [list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4) of properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton UIButtonTypeCustom] ;
button.frame = rect ;
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

you just need to use UIButtonTypeCustom, It's not necessary to set any backgroundColor or tintColor for UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

Answer (score 0):

just change one line use UIButtonTypeCustom instead of UIButtonTypeSystem

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] ;
button.frame = rect ;
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] ;
```